# Source of sequence?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I want to use source code of some sequences but i am unable to find it in ALL_SOURCE data dictionary.
Please let me know where i can find source code for sequences used .

Comment: Sequences are internal counters managed by Oracle, they are not code objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
  select * from ALL_SEQUENCES
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
select * from USER_SEQUENCES

This is for sequence created by user.

Answer (score 1):

`DBA_DEPENDENCIES / ALL_DEPENDENCIES` should tell you what sequences are used by what procedural code -- however, sequences used by dynamic SQL won't be caught.

To be able to view source code - like a package body - in another schema, you'll need the right privileges, and `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` is the simplest; otherwise, the DEBUG privilege on the package in the remote schema is required.